# Buttons that delete their StackPanel in WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a contacts app. When I try to edit a contact it opens a window that looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E9IS.png)

The code that loads the contact model is:

```
private void LoadContactToEdit() {
    FirstNameTextBox.Text = contactToEdit.FirstName;
    LastNameTextBox.Text = contactToEdit.LastName;
    string[] phoneNumbers = contactToEdit.PhoneNumbers.Split('|');

    int i = 0;
    foreach(string phoneNumber in phoneNumbers) {
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
        sp.Name = $ "PNStackPanel{i}";
        RegisterName(sp.Name, sp);
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
        txtbox.Name = $ "PNTextBox{i}";
        txtbox.Text = phoneNumber;
        txtbox.Width = 200;
        txtbox.Background = Brushes.White;
        txtbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

        sp.Children.Add(txtbox);

        if (i > 0) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = $ "PNButton{i}";
            btn.Content = btn.Name;
            btn.Width = 100;
            btn.Click += DeletePhoneNumberTextBox;
            btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

            sp.Children.Add(btn);
        }
        PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.Add(sp);

        i++;
    }

    string[] emailAddresses = contactToEdit.EmailAddresses.Split('|');

    i = 0;
    foreach(string emailAddress in emailAddresses) {
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        sp.Name = $ "EAStackPanel{i}";
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
        txtbox.Name = $ "EATextBox{i}";
        txtbox.Text = emailAddress;
        txtbox.Width = 200;
        txtbox.Background = Brushes.White;
        txtbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

        sp.Children.Add(txtbox);

        if (i > 0) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = $ "EAButton{i}";
            btn.Content = btn.Name;
            btn.Width = 100;
            //btn.Click += DeleteEmailAddressTextBox;
            btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

            sp.Children.Add(btn);
        }
        EmailAddressStackPanel.Children.Add(sp);

        i++;
    }

}
```

Look at the phone number code for now. I am trying to create buttons that dynamically deletes the stackpanel the are part of.
this is their code:

```
private void DeletePhoneNumberTextBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    string s = (sender as Button).Name;
    char c = s[s.Length - 1];
    string x = $ "PNStackPanel{c}";

    StackPanel sp = PhoneNumberStackPanel.FindName(x) as StackPanel;
    PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.Remove(sp);

}
```

However only the last button deletes its stackpanel. I tried messing with itemsControl instead of stackpanels and I only got more confused. What do I do wrong?

[EDIT]: I converted the StackPanel into ItemsControl after some researching and removing items is a lot easier.

Comment: "I tried messing with itemsControl instead of stackpanels and I only got more confused" - understanding of ItemsControl is a must-have skill for wpf development. with ItemsControl 90% of code above won't be necessary

Comment: Your question is not related to the development environment Visual Studio itself, so I've removed that tag. Hint: Use the little "i" next to the tag to get information about how to use it.